# Rollup with Gulp.js - Multiple outputs

Tags: rollupjs

I'm trying to use an array of outputs using Rollup on Gulp.

[The documentation](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/#gulp) only shows a basic example with a single output file. (Although it states that the `output` property can contain an array)

```js
.then(bundle => {
      return bundle.write({
        file: './dist/library.js',
        format: 'umd',
        name: 'library',
        sourcemap: true
      });
    });
```

If I replace that for an array, it will fail:

```js
.then(bundle => {
      return bundle.write({
        file: './dist/library.js',
        format: 'umd',
        name: 'library',
        sourcemap: true
      },
       {
        file: './dist/file2.js',
        format: 'umd',
      });
    });
```

> Error: You must specify "output.file" or "output.dir" for the build.
> at error (/Users/alvarotrigolopez/Sites/extensions/experiments/bundle/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:158:30)
> at handleGenerateWrite (/Users/alvarotrigolopez/Sites/extensions/experiments/bundle/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:23403:20)

I've tried using the `output` option as well and using `@rollup/stream` instead of just `rollup`.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var rollup = require('@rollup/stream');

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return rollup({
      input: './app.js',
      output: [
        {
          file: 'bundle.js',
          format: 'umd',
        },
        {
          file: 'test.js',
          format: 'umd',
        }
      ]
    })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});
```

> Unknown output options: 0, 1. Allowed options: amd, assetFileNames, banner, chunkFileNames, compact, dir, dynamicImportFunction, entryFileNames, esModule, exports, extend, externalLiveBindings, file, footer, format, freeze, generatedCode, globals, hoistTransitiveImports, indent, inlineDynamicImports, interop, intro, manualChunks, minifyInternalExports, name, namespaceToStringTag, noConflict, outro, paths, plugins, preferConst, preserveModules, preserveModulesRoot, sanitizeFileName, sourcemap, sourcemapExcludeSources, sourcemapFile, sourcemapPathTransform, strict, systemNullSetters, validate